# regular expression to remove only leading zeros in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Guys I have the input string +00000000995510.32 and I need to remove the + sign and the leading zeros, my output number should be: 995510.32.

Is there a regular expression to do this in `regexp_replace`?

My current code:

```py
df.withColumn("vl_fat",regexp_replace(col("vl_fat"),"^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])$+", ""))
```

but that didn't work

Comment: try `(\+[0]*)` https://regex101.com/r/yaZekl/1

Comment: Do you want an output *number* or an output *string*?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to practise regex, try: https://regex101.com/. The pattern you describe is that it starts with one `+` and then with a zero to many amount of `0`, which in python regex would be `[+][0]*`. You also need to consider the look ahead feature of regex that can get a little weird. This should work however:

```
(?![+])(?![0]).*
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regex you might like to use `TRIM`. I find this easier to read and it better conveys the intention of the code. Note this code will also remove any `+` signs directly after your leading zeros.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('+00000000995510.32',)], ['number'])
df.withColumn('trimmed', F.expr("TRIM(LEADING '+0' FROM number)")).show()

+------------------+---------+
|            number|  trimmed|
+------------------+---------+
|+00000000995510.32|995510.32|
+------------------+---------+
```

Or if you want an actual number, you could simply cast it to float (or decimal). Note any value which cannot be cast will become `NULL`.

```
df.withColumn('trimmed', F.col('number').cast('float')).show()

+------------------+--------+
|            number| trimmed|
+------------------+--------+
|+00000000995510.32|995510.3|
+------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex `"\+0+"` to catch the leading `+000...`

explanation from [regex101](https://regex101.com/) :

1. `\+` matches the character `+` literally (case sensitive)
2. `0` matches the character `0` literally (case sensitive)
3. `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: you can use `regex_extract` (that seems to suite better your use case) and convert the input string into a float:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('+00000000995510.32',),
     ('34.32',),
     ('+00000.34',),
     ('+0444444',),
     ('9.',)],
    T.StructType([
        T.StructField('input_string', T.StringType())
    ])
)

df.withColumn('parsed_float',
              F.regexp_extract('input_string', '^(\+0+|)(\d+(\.\d*|))$', 2).cast(T.FloatType()))
```

This is what you get:

```bash
+------------------+------------+
|      input_string|parsed_float|
+------------------+------------+
|+00000000995510.32|    995510.3|
|             34.32|       34.32|
|         +00000.34|        0.34|
|          +0444444|    444444.0|
|                9.|         9.0|
+------------------+------------+
```

For the regex:

- `(\+0+|)`: this captures the initial (optional) `+` followed by one or more `0`
- `(\d+(\.\d*|))`: this captures the whole figure, described as a sequence of numbers followed by a (optional) sequence composed of a `.` followed by any number of decimals

The second argument of `regex_extract` is the group you are interested into; in this case is the second one, i.e., `(\d+(\.\d*|))`.